# GSP compilation failed in grails

Tags: grails-2.2

When I run grails war I got the following error

Compiling 30 GSP files for package [appInfo].
| Error GSP Compilation error in file /WEB-INF/plugins/app-info-0.4.3/grails-app/views/appinfo/hibernateEntityInfo.gsp at line 69: Tag [each] missing required attribute [in]

I used 
grails 2.2.4
 and also I want to know the app-info plugin location in the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the problem with App-info plugin. I also got similar problem . I solved by following way

```
Clean the application using
```

grails Clean

```
then run the application using
```

grails RunApp

```
and make sure If you are using sequences in the application do not use mysql because mysql does not support sequences.
```